# Approaches to the size constrained weighted set cover problem

Tags: optimization, combinatorics, set-cover

I am trying to solve a weighted set cover problem where the number of selected subsets is limited by a constant $k$.
Assuming this is a pretty straight-forward variation of weighted set cover I ended up quite confused with only one, also rather recent paper by Golab et al. [1].

Am I missing something here?

[1] Golab, Korn, Li, Saha and Srivastava, *Size-constrained weighted set cover*. In _Proceedings of 31st International Conference on Data Engineering (ICDE), pp. 879–890. IEEE, 2015. [IEEE Digital Library](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7113341/); [author PDF](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~barna/paper/ICDE15_research_131.pdf).

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  1. Can you edit the question to provide a reference that will be as robust over time as possible? We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).  I suggest including the title, authors, and where it was published. 2. What exactly do you want to know about the problem?    3. If you can find one paper on a topic, it's often useful to check what other papers cite that one and what other papers it cites, to see if any of them have anything relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in P and can be solved in $O(m^k)$ time, where $m$ is the number of sets to select from.  For this reason, it is fundamentally different from standard set cover (which is NP-hard) and might not have been studied as much in the complexity theory literature.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please provide some link or reference? In the paper mentioned above the authors show NP-hardness in IV COMPLEXITY ANALYSIS for their problem.

Comment: @martin, in that paper, $k$ is part of the input, rather than a constant.  When $k$ is part of the input (i.e., unbounded), the problem is NP-complete.  When $k$ is fixed (e.g., 5), it is in P.